# Zoom whole content inside the div box

Tags: html, css

I want the whole content inside the div to zoom, but only div is zooming and content remaining same size. Something need to change in the CSS which I got from a free template and don't to know what to change. Any suggestions please?

```css
.product-item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 380px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-item::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 1px);
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  border: solid 2px rgba(235, 235, 235, 0);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.product-item:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 29px rgba(63, 78, 100, 0.15);
  border: solid 2px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="product_image">
    <img src="assets/images/product_3.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="favorite"></div>
  <div class="product_info">
    <h6 class="product_name"><a href="#">Mexican Pizza (Extra Toppings)</a></h6>
    <div class="product_price">$820.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_to_cart_button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not the div thats zooming at all - it's the div's ::after pseudo-element that is zooming.

Comment: I'm not sure why they'd use `::after` to achieve that effect. `box-shadow` transitions just fine - the hover could just expand and transition the shadow on the main element, no problem. Wherever you got that free template from - don't go back, it's pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ::after And you are good to go. You don't need to hover over the pseudo element.

```
.product-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 29px rgba(63, 78, 100, 0.15);
  border: solid 2px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```css
.product-item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 380px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-item::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 1px);
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  border: solid 2px rgba(235, 235, 235, 0);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.product-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 29px rgba(63, 78, 100, 0.15);
  border: solid 2px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="product_image">
    <img src="assets/images/product_3.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="favorite"></div>
  <div class="product_info">
    <h6 class="product_name"><a href="#">Mexican Pizza (Extra Toppings)</a></h6>
    <div class="product_price">$820.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_to_cart_button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but zoom is hiding behind other content, how to bring it on top?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean.

But if you need to bring the product_item class on top of everything give z-index to it. If that's what you are looking for.